# Retrieve container from DataGrid wpf by DataRow

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm using DataGrid in Wpf and bind data as following:

```
datagridEx.ItemsSource = tblEx.AsDataView();
```

Now i have a function which handling some logic then return a List of DataRow.
I want to set background for these rows

```
public void HighlightRows(IEnumerable<DataRow> rows, DataGrid grid)
{
    foreach(var row in rows)
    {
        DataGridRow dgr = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(row) as DataGridRow;
        if (dgr != null)
        {
            dgr.Background = Brushes.LightBlue; 
        }
    }
}
```

but i always recieve a null reference pointer of dgr. I realized that DataRow is converted to DataRowView therefore DataGrid could not found the container represent to DataRow item.

Which is good solution can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem()`, use `grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex()` function, because `DataGrid` uses virtualization so `Item` has not been generated at that time.

From the `ContainerFromIndex` function you can fetch `DataGridRow` and then you can use `DataGridRow.Item` to compare data rows.

Updated function is as below:

```
public void HighlightRows(IEnumerable<DataRow> rows, DataGrid grid)
{           
    for (int index = 0; index < grid.Items.Count; index++)
    {
        DataGridRow dgr = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as DataGridRow;

        if (dgr.Item.GetType() == typeof(DataRowView))
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in rows)
            {
                var array1 = row.ItemArray;
                var array2 = (((DataRowView)dgr.Item).Row).ItemArray;

                if (array1.SequenceEqual(array2))
                {
                    dgr.Background = Brushes.LightBlue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```